# tbb.dll not found

Tags: c++, c, opencv

I am using cvCanny function in opencv 2.3 it compiles fine,but while executing it gives an error saying 'tbb.dll' not found.

What is the use of this dll and where can I find this??

thanks,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's part of Intel's [Threading Building Blocks](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/) library.

You can find a copy of it in your OpenCV install in `/build/common/tbb` and under the platform and compiler your are using. For example, in `c:\OpenCV-2.3.1\build\common\tbb\intel64\vc9`

Comment: Thanks,
So do I need to download it and add it in my executables?

Comment: Just download it and put it in the directory from where you run your application or just into Windows/System32

Comment: Thanks the problem is solved..The dll is provided with the opencv2.3.But the path was not recognised.