# Emgu: Unable to load DLL. Device is not ready

Tags: dll, installation, emgucv

I am currently working to get Emgu set up for use on my computer.  I have Downloaded a 32 bit installation from sourceforge and installed it.  I have created a console project and added the following dll's as references:
 - Emgu.CV
 - Emgu.CV.DebuggerVisualizers.VS2010
 - Emgu.CV.GPU 
 - Emgu.CV.ML
 - Emgu.CV.OCR
 - Emgu.CV.Stitching
 - Emgu.CV.UI
 - Emgu.CV.VideoStab
 - Emgu.Util
(I know that I don't need all of these for each project, but I put them in anyway)

I also added opencv_core242.dll as well as the other dll's in the same folder to the output folder as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13875514/unable-to-load-dll-opencv-core242-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found-em) answer suggested.

I added the folder containing opencv_core242.dll to the as a path variable on my comp like [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vdjoutNR2DQ) video suggests.

However, I am still getting the following error

```
'Emgu.CV.CVInvoke' threw an exception. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'opencv_core242': The device is not ready. (Exception from HRESULT 0x80070015) ...
```

Any Ideas on what I am forgetting or what else I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed!!!
I downloaded the 64 bit version of EMGU but under the Configuration Manager for the solution it was trying to Debug in x86.  I just changed it to debug on Any CPU and problem solved.  Nothing wrong with the path or with the files I was using.

Answer (score 1):

AS the exception says your compiler is not able to opencv dll.

As an addition *`Device not Ready`* seems to indicate that you are referencing opencv dll's from an unreachable or protected path...