# Emgu.CV.CvInvoke' threw an exception FaceDetectionAndRecognition

Tags: c#, face-recognition, c#-2.0, detect, face

I have created an application in C# that, when triggered, opens the camera and detects a face, placing a square around it. When I run this application in debug mode, it works correctly. However, when I build a release version, it throws an exception.

```
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace FaceDetectionAndRecognition
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private HaarCascade faceDetected;
        private Image<Bgr, Byte> Frame;
        private Capture camera;
        private Image<Gray, byte> grayFace = null;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            faceDetected = new HaarCascade("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml");
            camera = new Capture();
            camera.QueryFrame();
            Application.Idle += new EventHandler(FrameProcedure);
            camera.FlipHorizontal = true;

        }

        private void FrameProcedure(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Frame = camera.QueryFrame().Resize(320, 240, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_CUBIC);
            grayFace = Frame.Convert<Gray, Byte>();
            MCvAvgComp[][] facesDetectedNow = grayFace.DetectHaarCascade(faceDetected, 1.2, 10, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.HAAR_DETECTION_TYPE.DO_CANNY_PRUNING, new Size(20, 20));

            foreach (MCvAvgComp f in facesDetectedNow[0])
            {
                Frame.Draw(f.rect, new Bgr(Color.Red), 2);
            }

            cameraBox.Size = new Size(640, 480);
            cameraBox.Image = Frame.ToBitmap();
        }
    }
}
```

And I receive this error, commonly referred to as an exception.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9pvd.png)

Can anyone help me find a solution to this issue?

Comment: Definitely explore this answer, I've had similar problems.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13875514/unable-to-load-dll-opencv-core242-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found-em

Comment: The release folder is missing a dll.  Look in the project folder for the bin directory.  The release and debug should have same dll in the folder.  You may of only compiled the debug version and not the release version. Dlls should never be manually put into the bin folder.  You should use Add Existing and browse to the child project debug folder.  The when you compile either the debug or release version the dll gets copied to the correct folder.

Comment: @ConnieMnemonic : You are referencing a link from 2012 and 2014.  Always check the dates on references to make sure they are still recent.